# Assigning array keys to looped data with Foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create my data with a new array. But when I assign an array, I want to print out the keys with their id. When I do the operation, ids are not added and array keys start from 0. What is the solution to this?

```php
$variantList = $this->variants;
        $variantOne = [];
        $variantTwo = [];
        $variantThree = [];
        foreach ($variantList as $value){
            if ($value->variant->type === 1){
                $variantOne[$value->variant_id] = $value->variant_option;
            }
            if ($value->variant->type === 2){
                $variantTwo[$value->variant_id] = $value->variant_option;
            }
            if ($value->variant->type === 3){
                $variantThree[$value->variant_id] = $value->variant_option;
            }
        }
```

output

```json
{
"variantOne": [
     0-   "BMW",
     1-   "213"
    ],
    "variantTwo": [
      0-  "Yeni",
      1-  "erwe"
    ],
    "variantThree": [
      0- "2024"
    ]
}
```

What I want is to display the ids written in variant_id.

Comment: Show us the `var_dump` of `$variantList`.

Comment: On the javascript side, I need to write the id in the key section. If I get the output in this way, I will press it directly to the screen. @GrumpyCrouton



```json
[
            "id" => 20
            "ads_id" => 16
            "variant_id" => 2
            "variant_option_id" => 1
            "variant_option" => "BMW"
            "created_at" => "2024-02-22 09:08:44"
            "updated_at" => "2024-02-22 09:08:44"
          ]
```

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with javascript. Update your question with the `var_dump` of `$variantList`. What you provided is not seem to be the full `$variantList`. If it is, then your c ode makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to do what I did in js rather than php. If anyone is stuck in this section, maybe I can help.

```php
foreach ($variantList as $value){
            if ($value->variant->type === 1){
                $variantOne[] = [
                    "id"    => $value->variant_id,
                    "value" => $value->variant_option,
                ];
            }
            if ($value->variant->type === 2){
                $variantTwo[] = [
                    "id"    => $value->variant_id,
                    "value" => $value->variant_option,
                ];
            }
            if ($value->variant->type === 3){
                $variantThree[] = [
                    "id"    => $value->variant_id,
                    "value" => $value->variant_option,
                ];
            }
        }
```

```js
let variantOneArray = []
      let variantTwoArray = []
      let variantThreeArray = []
      Object.values(r.data.variantOne).forEach((value, key) => {
        variantOneArray[value.id] = value.value
      });
      Object.values(r.data.variantTwo).forEach((value, key) => {
        variantTwoArray[value.id] = value.value
      });
      Object.values(r.data.variantThree).forEach((value, key) => {
        variantThreeArray[value.id] = value.value
      });
      variantOne.value = variantOneArray
      variantTwo.value = variantTwoArray
      variantThree.value = variantThreeArray
```

Comment: Those two don't appear to be equivalent, your PHP has `$variantOne`, `$variantTwo` and `$variantThree`, while your JS only has `variantOneArray`?

Comment: @ChrisHaas This is just an example for one data.

Comment: But in your JS I'm also not seeing you compare something with `1`, `2` or `3` as you are doing in PHP.